# Conflito entre number_format do php e parseFloat do javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Estou montando um sistema para calcular frete em php, ajax e javascript. A página  calcula-frete recebe um valor através da `number_format(($_SESSION['total']), 2, ',', '.')` que vem do carrinho de compras.

Depois de calculado o frete, apresento o valor total da compra (com o frete). Só que a soma não bate. Uma compra no valor de 1.575,30 com 17,20 de frete dá um total de 18.775. Acredito que esteja havendo um conflito entre o `number_format` e o `parseFloat` ou `replace` do javascript.

Seguem o html e o javascript. Se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço desde já.

```
<input id ="valor_produto" type ="text" value = "<?php echo number_format(($_SESSION['total']), 2, ',', '.'); ?>"/><br/><br/>
Cep Destino = <input id ="cep_destino" type ="text" value ="", maxlength ="8"/><br/><br/>
Valor Frete = <input id ="valor_frete" type ="text" value =""/><br/><br/>
Valor Total = <input id ="valor_total" type ="text" value =""/><br/><br/> 
<button type="button" onclick ="LoadFrete();">Calcular Frete</button>


function LoadFrete(){

var cep_destino = $('#cep_destino').val();
var valor_produto = $('#valor_produto').val();

$.ajax({
 url: 'ajax/a_frete.php',
 type: 'POST',
 dataType: 'html',
 cache: false,
 data: {cep_destino: cep_destino},
 success: function (data){

 console.log(data);

 $('#valor_frete').val(data);

 var valor_produto = $('#valor_produto').val();  

 var total = parseFloat(data) + parseFloat(valor_produto);

 $('#valor_total').val(total);

 $('#prazo_entrega').val(data);  

 }, beforeSend: function (){
 }, error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log('Erro');
 }

});
}
```

Comment: O `console.log(data);` que vem do json dá o que ? Qual o valor que tem `number_format(($_SESSION['total']), 2, ',', '.');` ?

Comment: Isac, o console não apresenta erro. Apenas mostra o valor do frete. O valor que vem da $_SESSION está correto: 1.050,20. O problema é a soma, que dá 18.775. Tirando o number_format, a soma fica correta, porém perco a milhar e a segunda casa decimal. Fica assim: 1050.2 + 17,20 (frete) = 1067.2. Obg por ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.575,30 não é um numero que se possa utilizar em cálculos matemáticos. Você não digita isso na sua maquina de calcular física ou virtual para realizar um calculo. Você digitaria 1575.30

Em programação também vale a mesma regra, os números devem ser do tipo inteiro ou, parte inteira separada por ponto seguida da parte fracionaria, `parteinteira.partefracionaria`

```
//tratando string para formato válido para calculos matematicos
//retira os pontos (.) dos separadores de milhar
 valor_produto = valor_produto.replace(/\./g, '');

//caso frete venha a ter separador de milhar
//frete = frete.replace(/\./g, '');

//transforma virgula (,) em ponto (.)
valor_produto=valor_produto.replace(",",".");
frete=frete.replace(",",".");
```

**Exemplo**

```js
function LoadFrete(){
 var frete;
 var cep_destino = $('#cep_destino').val();
 var valor_produto = $('#valor_produto').val();
 
  valor_produto = valor_produto.replace(/\./g, '');
 
  valor_produto=valor_produto.replace(",",".");
 
  frete = $('#valor_frete').val();  
  
  frete=frete.replace(",","."); 
 
  var total = parseFloat(frete) + parseFloat(valor_produto);
 
     $('#valor_total').val(((total).toFixed(2).replace(".", ",")).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "."));

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id ="valor_produto" type ="text" value = "1.050,20"/><br/><br/>
Valor Frete = <input id ="valor_frete" type ="text" value =""/><br/><br/>
Valor Total = <input id ="valor_total" type ="text" value =""/><br/><br/> 
<button type="button" onclick ="LoadFrete();">Calcular Frete</button>
```

Comment: Leo, entendo o que vc diz sobre soma. No carrinho de compras só uso o number_format para exibir corretamente o total depois de somados todos os valores. Tirando o number_format da $_SESSION['total'], a soma fica correta: 1050.2 + 17,20 (frete) = 1067.2. Porém perco a milhar e a segunda casa decimal. Com o number_format, o total vem correto (1.050,20). Porém a soma fica errada (18.775) e sem casa decimal. O que eu preciso é somar o total que vem do carrinho de compras com o frete e depois formatar com ponto e vírgula. Obg por tentar ajudar.

Comment: @CarlosAguiar, não, não está correto, sem levar em consideração a virgula a soma 1050.2 + 17,20 = 1067.4  Voce precisa tratar esse 17virgula20 para 17ponto20 para dar o resultado correto. depois para exibir com ponto e virgula aplique `     $('#valor_total').val(((total).toFixed(2).replace(".", ",")).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "."));

Comment: @CarlosAguiar se vc não aplica number_format o valor vem no formato que possa se fazer uma operação matematica, ou seja, 1050.2 somente com ponto na casa decimal. E o valor do frete que tem virgula como separador decimal só é levado em conta a parte antes da virgula, ou seja 17 dando 1067.2

Comment: @CarlosAguiar veja na resposta editada que coloquei o valor `1.050,20` como se estivesse formatado pela função `number_format`. Digite lá no valor do frete 17,20 (com virgula ou mesmo com ponto) e veja o resultado

Comment: É isso mesmo. Diferentemente do formato brasileiro (talvez o mesmo europeu, não tenho certeza), qualquer número em programação deve ter o formato americano: 1,234.56 ou 1234.56: a vírgula separa os milhares e o ponto as casas decimais.

Comment: Olá, Leo. Eu fiz do jeito que vc explicou e a soma dá certo. O problema é que no valor total não aparecem o '.' do milhar e o '0' da segunda casa decimal. Um produto com valor de 1000,00 e frete com valor de 17,20 fica 1017.2. O valor do frete vem dos Correios. Não tenho como tratá-lo. Enfim, o problema agora é o replace. Obg, Carlos.

Comment: @CarlosAguiar acho que um de nossos PCs está destoando! Descomentei o código que faz formatar com separadores de milhar e retirei o que estava antes. Se colocar 17,20 no frete eu vejo aqui no meu PC 1.067,40

Comment: @CarlosAguiar Se você não puder tratar o valor q vem do correio os centavos não serão levados em consideração nos cálculos, haverá perdas e Jacó não vai gostar nada disso :)

Comment: Agora ficou perfeito. Coloquei o <script> na mesma página do html. Antes estava em outra, com o caminho no <head>. Mas não entendi direito o porquê de não dar certo do outro jeito. Também fiz dois <input>. Um com a $_SESSION formatada para moeda (para o usuário) e um type hidden (para o cálculo).  Obg pela força...e pela paciência. Abçs